# storybook : Unable to resolve module path from node_modules/@storybook/store/dist/cjs/autoTitle.js

Tags: react-native, storybook

I'm using a storybook with a react native project and this project is inside a lerna project. while running `yarn && yarn start` in one terminal then `yarn run-android` I have this error:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module path from /home/front/node_modules/@storybook/store/dist/cjs/autoTitle.js: path could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
  38 | var _startCase = _interopRequireDefault(require("lodash/startCase"));
  39 | 
> 40 | var _path = _interopRequireDefault(require("path"));
     |                                             ^
  41 | 
  42 | var _slash = _interopRequireDefault(require("slash"));
  43 | 
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/front/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:129:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/front/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at Object.resolve (/home/front/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (/home/front/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at /home/front/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/home/front/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (/home/front/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Done in 451.87s.
```

This file `/home/front/node_modules/@storybook/store/dist/cjs/autoTitle.js` do exists. so for me The storybook need to know how to look for this file but I don't know how to tell him.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again ?